# What power are you measuring after a PWM Switch for a DC Motor?

Tags: power, motor, pwm

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1H9b0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you are using PWM for a brushed motor and you place a power meter *after* the switch without any time-gating (it just measures continuously all the time), are you measuring any coherent singular power? Or is it just an incoherent mashup of power from the supply and the free-wheeling energy stored in the coil's magnetic field?

**EDIT:** Actually, the free wheeling power subtracts from the supply power so...what *is* that?